# Scheduled rule email only sent after page request

Tags: drupal, cron, scheduled-tasks, rules

I have a scheduled rule that sends a email to users 30 mins prior to the value of a CCK date field in a node. The rule works correctly but cron only runs when a user makes a page request. I installed the ultimate cron module and set it to run cron every 1 minute but again it only runs when a user requests a page.

How can I run cron every minute so that the emails get sent without users having to visit the site for cron to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what version of drupal you use. For D7, when you go to Cron settings page you'll see something like:

```
Last run: 4 min 33 sec ago.

To run cron from outside the site, go to http://....
```

So, as it says, you should provide the way that this page is called by server cron service time to time and when that happens your site cron jobs  will be executed.

I guess there must be some similar thing for D8 also.

And you can set server's cron from console or it may be doable from some control panel. Contact your host provider for details. There are some external cron services, some of them are even free:

https://cron-job.org/en/

Comment: Thanks for the help, running crom from the server got it working!